# How many frames do you have to 'tech' in Super Smash Bros Wii U?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In Super Smash Bros Wii U (or Smash 4), it is a common strategy to 'tech.' This is when you press the shield button right before you hit the ground or wall of the stage, to avoid bouncing back up or just laying there.

In order to execute a tech correctly, you must time your button input correctly. There is a small window right before your character hits the stage that you can press the shield button. Does anyone know the length of this period, in frames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The time period that you have to tech before hitting a surface (wall, ground, ceiling, etc) is 20 frames.**

From the [wiki page](http://www.ssbwiki.com/tech) (emphasis mine):

> To tech, the user must press the shield button **20 frames or fewer before hitting the surface**; after that, a player won't be able to tech for 40 frames.

Also note the 40 frame cool down before you can attempt to tech again.